# Two Phase Commit Using Spring framework

Tags: java, spring, db2, mq, xa

I need help about implementing Two phase commit.

My requirement:

I have a application in which I take a record from a DB2 table and process it internally and push the processed record as a XML into MQ and also update the DB2 that the record is processed successfully. So that it will avoid getting the same record again for processing.

If anyone of the two process(pushing into MQ, updating int DB2) fails the other process must fail.

If I can achieve this processes in any other way, Please let me know.

Comment: Can the order be switched ?

Comment: Make the proces transactional and configure a `JtaTransactionManager` however I would suggest not using 2PC but use a single transaction manager and make your setup robust so that it can handle duplicated messages. That way it will be simpler and probably faster.

Comment: yes we can switch the order